# Heartbeat Protocols/Algorithms or best practices

Tags: sockets, network-programming, network-protocols, distributed-computing

Recently I've added some load-balancing capabilities to a piece of software that I wrote. It is a networked application that does some data crunching based on input coming from a SQL database. Since the crunching can be pretty intensive I've added the capability to have multiple instances of this application running on different servers to split the load but as it is now the load balancing is a manual act. A user must specify which instances take which portion of the input domain.

I would like to take that to the next level and program the instances to automatically negotiate the diving up of the input data and to recognize if one of them "disappears" (has crashed or has been powered down) so that the remaining instances can take on the failed instance's workload.

In order to implement this I'm considering using a simple heartbeat protocol between the instances to determine who's online and who isn't and while this is not terribly complicated I'd like to know if there are any established heartbeat network protocols (based on UDP, TCP or both).

Obviously this happens a lot in the networking world with clustering, fail-over and high-availability technologies so I guess in the end I'd like to know if maybe there are any established protocols or algorithms that I should be aware of or implement.

**EDIT**

It seems, based on the answers, that either there are no well established heart-beat protocols or that nobody knows about them (which would imply that they aren't so well established after all) in which case I'm just going to roll my own.

While none of the answers offered what I was looking for specifically I'm going to vote for [Matt Davis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442189/heartbeat-protocols-algorithms-or-best-practices/1442901#1442901) since it was the closest and he pointed out a good idea to use multicast.

Thank you all for your time~

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to customize WebLogic's native heartbeat messages, to add some additional information such as current CPU and/or network load? (to allow load-balancing algorithms that use that information to avoid overloading a struggling server with more requests)

Comment: That's more of a question for Pascal (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442189/heartbeat-protocols-algorithms-or-best-practices/1442255#1442255). I'm not that familiar with WebLogic - in my case I ended up using what I had already started working on which was a custom solution based on UDP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Distribued Interactive Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Interactive_Simulation) (DIS), which is defined under [IEEE](http://standards.ieee.org/) Standard 1278, uses a default heartbeat of 5 seconds via UDP broadcast.  A DIS heartbeat is essentially an Entity State PDU, which fully defines the state, including the position, of the given entity.  Due to its application within the simulation community, DIS also uses a concept referred to as dead-reckoning to provide higher frequency heartbeats when the actual position, for example, is outside a given threshold of its predicted position.

In your case, a DIS Entity State PDU would be overkill.  I only mention it to make note of the fact that heartbeats can vary in frequency depending on the circumstances.  I don't know that you'd need something like this for the application you described, but you never know.

For heartbeats, use UDP, not TCP.  A heartbeat is, by nature, a connectionless contrivance, so it goes that UDP (connectionless) is more relevant here than TCP (connection-oriented).

The thing to keep in mind about UDP broadcasts is that a broadcast message is confined to the [broadcast domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain).  In short, if you have computers that are separated by a layer 3 device, e.g., a router, then broadcasts are not going to work because the router will not transmit broadcast messages from one broadcast domain to another.  In this case, I would recommend using multicast since it will span the broadcast domains, providing the time-to-live (TTL) value is set high enough.  It's also a more automated approach than directed unicast, which would require the sender to know the IP address of the receiver in order to send the message.

Answer (score 6):

Broadcast a heartbeat every t using UDP; if you haven't heard from a machine in more than k*t, then it's assumed down.  Be careful that the aggregate bandwidth used isn't a drain on resources.  You can use IP broadcast addresses, or keep a list of specific IPs you're doing work for.

Make sure the heartbeat includes a "reboot count" as well as "machine ID" so that you know previous server state isn't around.

I'd recommend using [MapReduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/) if it fits.  It would save a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, the the very basic UDP pattern you mention is exactly what I had in mind. The MapReduce is certainly something I'll have to look into but I won't be able to use it for this application because the app is already implemented differently.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this will answer the question but you might be interested by the way Weblogic Server clustering work under the hood. From the book [Mastering BEA WebLogic Server](http://books.google.com/books?id=Eg8UvYoA4gYC):

> [...] WebLogic Server clustering provides a loose coupling of the servers in the cluster. Each server in the cluster is independent and does not rely on any other server for any fundamental operations. Even if contact with every other server is lost, each server will continue to run and be able to process the requests it receives. Each server in the cluster maintains its own list of other servers in the cluster through periodic heartbeat messages. Every 10 seconds, each server sends a heartbeat message to the other servers in the cluster to let them know it is still alive. Heartbeat messages are sent using IP multicast technology built into the JVM, making this mechanism efficient and scalable as the number of servers in the cluster gets large. Each server receives these heartbeat messages from other servers and uses them to maintain its current cluster membership list. If a server misses receiving three heartbeat messages in a row from any other server, it takes that server out of its membership list until it receives another heartbeat message from that server. This heartbeat technology allows servers to be dynamically added and dropped from the cluster with no impact on the existing servers’ configurations.

Comment: Multicast may not work over a WAN. The advantage of multicast IMO is that you don't need to know how you're sending to (don't need to configure a list of nodes or peers).

Comment: Agreed with both points. BTW, I should have mentioned that, starting with Weblogic 10, BEA/Oracle supports communication between cluster members using Unicast (which is encouraged) in addition to Multicast.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to customize WebLogic's native heartbeat messages, to add some additional information such as current CPU and/or network load? (to allow load-balancing algorithms that use that information to avoid overloading a struggling server with more requests)

Comment: @XpiritO Please open a new question for this (properly tagged etc). The comment system is not ideal to answer questions, your queston may be useful for other readers and you may get better answers than just mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Cisco content switches are a hardware solution for this problem.  They implement a virtual IP address as a front end to multiple real servers, whose real IP addresses are known to the switch.  The switch periodically sends HTTP HEAD requests to the web servers, to verify they are still running (which the switch software calls a "keepalive", although this doesn't keep the server itself alive).  The Cisco switch accepts traffic on the virtual IP and forwards it to the actual web servers, using configurable load balancing such as round-robin, or user-defined load balancing.

These switches retail in the $3-10K range, although my business partner picked one up on eBay for about $300 a year ago.  If you can afford one, they do represent a proven hardware solution to the question of how to have a service spread transparently across multiple servers.  Redhat includes a built-in port configuration so that you could implement your own Cisco switch using a cheap RedHat box.  Google for "virtual ip address" and "cisco content router" for more information.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the tip but those switches only allow you to know whether the server is still alive and not whether the app is still running - which is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Ah, in our case, the server *is* the app. But you might look into the Linux-based option - since your app is already distributed, it must have some communication infrastructure, so you might be able to piggyback on that to provide a polling interface to the front-end.  Most of these options offer a custom keepalive interface, so you could write your own method.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to trying hardware load-balancers, you can also try a free-open-source load-balancing software application such as [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), available for Linux and the BSDs.